# URL iteration in Jinja

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have two lists. One scrapes the link text from Google News and the other contains the link.

```
return render_template('news.html', link_text=link_t, link_addr=links_h)
```

How do I make clickable headlines in Jinja. I have done this.

```
{%for item in range(0, 30)%}
    <div class="border">
        <li><a href=" {{ link_addr[i] }}" >{{ link_text[i] }}</a></li>

    </div>
         {%endfor%}
```

I know this won't work for the `href` part(I don't know the correct format). It makes the headlines appear neatly. However I don't know how to link the headline to the matching `href`. They need to be in  a `<div>` inside the `<li>` element.Please Help.

Comment: Since link text are related to link addr instead of using 2 separate list, a reccomendation would be to transform it into key,value pair, i.e a python dict. That way you would not have to hard code the range and keep track of 2 separate lists

Comment: I considered that. However, while scraping I was not able to scrape the link and the link text together. If I did that I was not able to make them "clickable". Plus, sometimes either the link would return None or sometimes the 'href' would return None. So, what would happen there is you would click on a link but it would take it to a different news. All in all, this was the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Tried different variations and this one worked. Strange,I thought I already tried this.

```
<li><a href=" {{ link_addr[i] }}" >{{ link_text[i] }}</a></li>
```

This gives clickable headlines perfectly.